# Azure AD - HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized - Windows Service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, jwt, azure-active-directory

Have a issue with Azure Auth. Getting 401 Unauthorized when calling WebAPI Hosted in Azure.

Here's the basics:
Followed this tutorial - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/

Registered 2 Applications:

1. Windows Service
2. WebAPI

The Windows Service calls STS and Succesfully gets a JWT. It then tries to pass that token to the WebAPI hosted on azurewebsites.net.

Here is my code to call the STS (Just wrapped in a Auth Class):

```
public class AzureAuth
{

    private AuthenticationContext authContext;
    private ClientCredential clientCredential;

    protected string AzureADInstanceName;
    protected string AzureADTenancyName;

    protected string AzureADApplicationClientId;
    protected string AzureADApplicationSecret;
    protected string AzureADApplicationAppId;


    public AzureAuth(string azureADInstanceName, string azureADTenancyName, string azureADApplicationClientId, string azureADApplicationSecret, string azureADApplicationAppId)
    {
        this.AzureADInstanceName = azureADInstanceName;
        this.AzureADTenancyName = azureADTenancyName;
        this.AzureADApplicationClientId = azureADApplicationClientId;
        this.AzureADApplicationSecret = azureADApplicationSecret;
        this.AzureADApplicationAppId = azureADApplicationAppId;

        string authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, AzureADInstanceName, AzureADTenancyName);
        this.authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        this.clientCredential = new ClientCredential(AzureADApplicationClientId, AzureADApplicationSecret);
    }

    public async Task ExecuteGetWithAADAutToken<T>(Action<AuthenticationResult> AfterAuthAction)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        try
        {
            result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(this.AzureADApplicationAppId, this.clientCredential);
            AfterAuthAction(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm then using that Auth class and the AuthResult to call the WebApi:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(getEndPointUri);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", res.AccessToken);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/api/field");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var resultStringJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(resultStringJSON);
    }
    else
    {
        var resulterrorStringJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(resulterrorStringJSON);
    }
}
```

The HttpResponseMessage response is giving Unauthorised

I used fiddler to get the Request and Response:

```
GET https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/someapi HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXX
Host: xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net


HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=697493f3974009aeb448f562d1b389f79aa6008071be1244c77f3f1d3849f5f0;Path=/;Domain=xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 03:59:15 GMT
```

Help please?

The main problem I suspect is that in Azure, the AAD Application does not have access to the Web API App. I tried to add it via Users but when I search that Application as user it can't find it. The Registered applications are in a different Azure AD Directory.

Comment: By chance did you enable Authentication / Authorization in the portal?  Several people have run into similar problems when they use both the integrated Authentication / Authorization AND the OWIN Azure AD authentication middleware in the same web app.

Comment: Hi @Phillippe. Yes I did enable that Authentication in the Web App in the Portal. Is that not neccessary?

Comment: Sorry, @ChrisGillum. You posted that comment.

Comment: @ChrisGillum. Just had a lightbulb moment. You are correct. I did enable that Azure Auth setting which was incorrect! That auth is where the prblem lies. I asume this UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication is all that's needed

Comment: What api do you want to call? The error indicates your access token cant access that api...

Comment: Thank @Lily_user4045. Problem found.Need to just test it but Chris solved it with his answer

Comment: @ChrisGillum. If you can post yours as answer I will mark it as the answer :-)

Comment: @Fox great! I've posted my comment as an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By chance did you enable Authentication / Authorization in the portal? Several people have run into similar problems when they use both the integrated Authentication / Authorization AND the OWIN Azure AD authentication middleware in the same web app. The correct way to setup your app is to use one or the other because they don't currently play nice together.

Comment: Removed Azure AD Auth and that fixed it.